# C++ variable scope for references

Tags: c++, scope

I'm writing some C++ for the first time in a very long time and can't remember much. I'm currently struggling the most with scope (along with when to use pointers vs references for input parameters). Specifically, if I create something on the stack, how long does it remain there?

If I have a simple class like:

```
class Person {
    const std::string name_;

public:
    Person(const std::string& name) : name_(name) {}
    const std::string& get_name() { return name_; }
};
```

And then I have a simple Person Generator method and main:

```
Person* get_person() {
    std::string name = "Bob";
    return new Person(name);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    Person* person = get_person();
    // Is person's name Bob here? Or did Bob go out of scope?
    delete person;
}
```

Before I delete person, did the person's name already go out of scope?

I understand I could create a new std::string and pass that to Person, but then I have one more variable to cleanup. Is the standard to accept pointers or references in method signatures?

Also, any references to tutorials on this subject are welcome.

Comment: _"Specifically, if I create something on the stack, how long does it remain there?"_ There's nothing going _on the stack_ in your sample (besides the `person` pointer variable).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ He is talking about `name` in `get_person()` which is then copied in the `Person` constructor.

Comment: @clcto Well, besides `name` in `get_person()` also.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break it down:

```
Person* get_person() {
    std::string name = "Bob"; // 1)
    return new Person(name); // 2)
} // 3)
```

1. The string name is created

   Here the string `name` is created on the stack.
2. A new person is created on the heap

   We have to look into the constructor to see what's going on

```
class Person {
    const std::string name_; 
public:
    Person(const std::string& name) : // 2.a)
        name_(name) // 2.b)
    {} // 2.c)

}
```

a) `name` is passed by reference. A reference to `name` lives in the current frame and `name` lives on the stack in the previous frame.

b) `name` is *copy constructed* into `name_`. Because the person is created on the heap, `name_` lives on the heap, too.

c) The reference to `name` is destroyed, because its scope ends.

3. The block ends, thus `name` is going out-of-scope. We return a pointer to a `Person` which lives on the heap, thus `Person` - with its `name_` - isn't going to get destroyed.

The most important step is `2.b)`. Here the name that lived on the *stack* is copy-constructed into the *heap*. This is because `name_` is not a reference but a value, which makes it "independant" from the `name` passed in.

---

Tl;dr the person's name doesn't go out-of-scope because only values on the stack can get out-of-scope. In this case only a pointer to the person lies on the stack, whereas the person - along with its name - is created on the heap (via `new`) and doesn't go out-of-scope.

Comment: Very accurate, I upvoted. Though you could expand on step 2a, that there's now the original string (in the previous stack frame) and a reference to it (in the current frame) on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

You have no issues here. The constructor of `Person` copies the value that was on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine.

When you pass the reference to name to the constructor, the constructor will make a new string from it, i.e. name_ will be a copy of name and be placed in the heap.

The variable name is out of scope after returning from get_person but a copy has already been made.

So - no problem.

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

```
copy (2): string (const string& str);

(2) copy constructor Constructs a copy of str.
```

Answer (score 1):

Something allocated on the stack will stay there for as long as the stack is relevant, and are immediately destroyed when the stack is popped.

C++ tends to employ two methods of getting data off the stack: Allocating on the heap so it persists longer than the current stack scope does, and copying.

Your `name` variable is a stack-allocated `std::string` but this is copied over to the C++ object you allocate since you pass it by reference, not pointer.

Internally the string data itself may be allocated on the heap, that's how these containers often work, but that's not really your concern here.

So in short, stack objects persist for the duration of their scope (e.g. function or block) unless they're heap-allocated or copied elsewhere.

From a stylistic point of view, what you really want to do is fold all of your `Person` concerns into the class. If `"Bob"` is a default name, make a constructor method that assigns that:

```
Person() : name_("Bob") { };
```

This avoids the `get_person()` confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In your code Person's name would be bob there.

Method signatures typically accept references, however there are times where you want to pass by copy.

This might be a useful reference for method signatures. 
http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/z6vU7k9E/